# Proxy For apt update Not Working

Tags: networking, apt, 12.04, updates, proxy

i Recently Restart my ubuntu 22.04

and when i Run want to update OS
with : `sudo apt update`

I Get Proxy Problem Connection :

> 0% [Connecting to proxy_address] [Connecting to proxy_address]
> [Connecting to proxy_address] [Connecting to proxy_address]
> [Connecting to proxy_address] [Connecting to proxy_address]^C